# Getting django stripe payments to return user history

Tags: django, stripe-payments

Im trying to configure [django-stripe-payments](https://github.com/eldarion/django-stripe-payments) to work properly. I'm using the following along with it:

- pinax-project-account(https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account)
- bootstrap-ajax (https://github.com/eldarion/bootstrap-ajax)

The trouble is that django-stripe-payments is not showing me my information in the template, such as my payment history or if my subscription is active even though it is.

Stripe is indeed picking up the payments and customer creations.

Has anyone got it working who can offer me some advice?

I understand this question is vague, I just don't know where the problem is.

[Image of the the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT7Xr.png)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out Jesramz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup webhooks:

1. In Stripe dashboard go to Your Account and then Webhooks
2. Add a URL to a publicly reachable URL that is where you are testing (if running local dev runserver, I have found [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) to be immensely useful)
3. Now when you make purchases you should see the data show up within seconds.

django-stripe-payments is designed around processing events data sent from webhooks.